# How does Data have hair?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Since Data is an inorganic Android, how does he grow *organic* hair?

Comment: Who said his hair is organic?

Comment: He's not entirely inorganic.  He himself states that he must consume a nutritional substance upon occasion, and his "blood" is partially organic, much like the gel packs on Voyager.

Comment: Data's main goal is to become human, so it's only reasonable he should look like the part. But It's probably just a really minor detail.

Comment: @Tim he doesn't *require* a nutritional substance, but rather a lubricant that happens to be semi-organic.

Comment: @corsiKa Data himself describes it as "nutritional" : (From Deja-Q) `Although I do not require sustenance, I occasionally ingest a semi-organic nutrient suspension in a silicon-based liquid medium.`  For a human analogy you might consider it the difference between food and vitamins - the former is required to provide a primary energy source but the latter to maintain health and vital function.  We can conclude that Data has alternate means to provide his primary energy source for operation but does still need to take vitamins, of a sort.

Comment: @mr.eaver More like, Dr. Soong's the one who gave Data hair, before Data ever drew a breath or thought a thought about his own goals.

Comment: Then I should've said Dr.Soong did make Androids in the image of humans, Particularly of himself and one, of his wife. So it would be reasonable that they should look as human as possible on the outside. Anyway as for actually how he grows hair, The answers given above and below explain it well.

Answer (score 55):

Data has **artificial hair follicles**. They can (presumably) take nutrients from what he consumes and convert those into a hair-like substance.

> **BASHIR:** *Does your hair grow?*
>
> **DATA:** ***I can control the rate of my follicle replenishment.** However, I have not yet had a reason to modify the length of my hair.
> Why do you ask?*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Birthright, Part I](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/242.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: He also "grew a beard" at one point.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean organic.  Non-organic things "grow" too, (like those grade school grow-a-crystal experiments), could be nanobots, etc.  I think the right answer is that we don't know that it's organic or not, just that it could plausibly be either.

Comment: So... 30 years ago Data preempted this exact question - why do you ask?